# Unable to subtract an integer value in javaScript Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I need to compare an array length with the text displaying numbers in the UI. I stored the array length in 'X' variable, whereas the text in 'len' variable.

I need to reduce the X by 3 and compare with the string 'len'.

EG: Len value is '+31' which is string. and X value is 34.

Please help me out to compare both the values. I tried converting both to string or int. Nothing helps me out.

```
    var len=createMenu.numPrivSelected.getText();
    var x=createMenu.returnLength(createMenu.selectedpriv);
    console.log(len+","+x-3);

    expect(len).toEqual(x);
```

**returnLength()** is a method which returns the length of the element.
**numPrivSelected** is an element which returns text as '+31'.

Output is:

> NaN
>
> Expected '+31' to equal 34.

Answer (score 0):

Well first, your `console.log` is return `NaN` because it's trying to do arithmetic on the string.

```js
console.log(len+","+x-3);
```

It would go like this:

```
len+","+x-3
"+31,"+x-3
"+31,34"-3
```

And obviously "string minus integer" won't work, so that's why it resulting in NaN (Not a Number).

Secondly, if you want to compare two numbers you need to make sure they're both numbers. The `+` sign in `len` makes it a string, and it can't be converted to a number directly. First you'll have to remove the plus sign. Here's your code, adjusted to fix the obvious errors that I can see:

```js
    var len=createMenu.numPrivSelected.getText();
    var x=createMenu.returnLength(createMenu.selectedpriv);

    len = len.replace("+","");
    x -= 3;
    console.log(len+","+x);

    expect(len).toEqual(x);
```

Comment: I'm facing this error, Failed: len.replace is not a function

Comment: @Renu That's strange, `len` must not be a string. Do you know what type `len` is? If not, try replacing `len = len.replace("+","");` with `len = len.toString().replace("+","");`.

Comment: Its because of some promises, i have tried as below and posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried as below and it worked,

```
 var len;
    var x;
    createMenu.returnLength(createMenu.selectedpriv).then(function(num){
        len=num-3;
        console.log(len);
    });

    createMenu.numPrivSelected.getText().then(function(text){
        x=text.replace("+","");
        console.log(x);
    });
    expect(len).toEqual(x);
```

Comment: The above statement is working in a wrong way. Since both `len` and `x` are undefined by default, `expect(len).toEqual(x) will look like expect(undefined).toEqual(undefined)` which will always pass.

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj yes:(, its returning undefined..its returning its value only inside loop. any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work,

```
var len = createMenu.returnLength(createMenu.selectedpriv).then(function(num){
    return num-3;
});

var x = createMenu.numPrivSelected.getText().then(function(text){
    return parseInt(text.replace("+",""));
});

expect(len).toEqual(x);
```

Comment: facing the same issue as before `Expected 31 to equal '31'.` and i tried to convert len.toString(), if so facing this issue. `Expected 'ManagedPromise::42875 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}' to equal '31'.`

Comment: i have updated as below and now its working fine. `var len=createMenu.returnLength(createMenu.selectedpriv).then(function(num){
            num=num-3;
            return num.toString();
            
        });

        var x=createMenu.numPrivSelected.getText().then(function(text){
            return text.replace("+","");
        });


        expect(len).toEqual(x); `